# How to create a edit profile page for users on frontend with custom fields on wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

How to create a edit profile page for users on frontend with custom fields on wordpress? I tried using profile builder plugin but cannot insert custom fields like gender radio box etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add extra user fields in wp-admin, for the users.
Use this in your functions.php, or in your plugin folder:

```
//extra user info in wp-admin
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'yoursite_extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'yoursite_extra_user_profile_fields' );
function yoursite_extra_user_profile_fields( $user ) {
?>
  <h3><?php _e("Extra profile information", "blank"); ?></h3>
  <table class="form-table">
    <tr>
      <th><label for="company"><?php _e("Company"); ?></label></th>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="company" id="company" class="regular-text" 
            value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'company', $user->ID ) ); ?>" /><br />
    </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <th><label for="job"><?php _e("Job"); ?></label></th>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="job" id="job" class="regular-text" 
            value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'job', $user->ID ) ); ?>" /><br />
    </td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
      <th><label for="country"><?php _e("Country"); ?></label></th>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="country" id="country" class="regular-text" 
            value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'country', $user->ID ) ); ?>" /><br />
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><label for="city"><?php _e("City"); ?></label></th>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="regular-text" 
            value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'city', $user->ID ) ); ?>" /><br />
    </td>
    </tr>     
    <tr>
      <th><label for="phone"><?php _e("Phone"); ?></label></th>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="regular-text" 
            value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'phone', $user->ID ) ); ?>" /><br />
    </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
<?php
}
```

After that you must save your fields when editing in wp-admin

```
//Save our extra registration user meta.
add_action('user_register', 'myplugin_user_register'); 
function myplugin_user_register ($user_id) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['phone'] ) )
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'phone', $_POST['phone']);   

    if ( isset( $_POST['company'] ) )
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'company', $_POST['company']);

    if ( isset( $_POST['job'] ) )
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'job', $_POST['job']);   

    if ( isset( $_POST['country'] ) )
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'country', $_POST['country']);   

    if ( isset( $_POST['city'] ) )
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'city', $_POST['city']);

    if ( isset( $_POST['user_interest'] ) )
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_interest', $_POST['user_interest']);

}
```

This functions will add custom fields to your users.

After that, in the frontend, of course you can use wp_insert_user(); function and wp_update_user(); to register and edit a user with all custom fields you created.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I already added extra custom fields in registration form on frontend using pie register plugin. But I want to add a edit profile form on frontend where my users can edit their own profile having those fields on frontend. Please help.

Answer (score 7):

You can do that by copy your theme's page.php to a new file named something like user-profile.php  and add to the very top of it this code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: User Profile
 *
 * Allow users to update their profiles from Frontend.
 *
 */

/* Get user info. */
global $current_user, $wp_roles;
//get_currentuserinfo(); //deprecated since 3.1

/* Load the registration file. */
//require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/registration.php' ); //deprecated since 3.1
$error = array();    
/* If profile was saved, update profile. */
if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'update-user' ) {

    /* Update user password. */
    if ( !empty($_POST['pass1'] ) && !empty( $_POST['pass2'] ) ) {
        if ( $_POST['pass1'] == $_POST['pass2'] )
            wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $current_user->ID, 'user_pass' => esc_attr( $_POST['pass1'] ) ) );
        else
            $error[] = __('The passwords you entered do not match.  Your password was not updated.', 'profile');
    }

    /* Update user information. */
    if ( !empty( $_POST['url'] ) )
        wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $current_user->ID, 'user_url' => esc_url( $_POST['url'] ) ) );
    if ( !empty( $_POST['email'] ) ){
        if (!is_email(esc_attr( $_POST['email'] )))
            $error[] = __('The Email you entered is not valid.  please try again.', 'profile');
        elseif(email_exists(esc_attr( $_POST['email'] )) != $current_user->id )
            $error[] = __('This email is already used by another user.  try a different one.', 'profile');
        else{
            wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $current_user->ID, 'user_email' => esc_attr( $_POST['email'] )));
        }
    }

    if ( !empty( $_POST['first-name'] ) )
        update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'first_name', esc_attr( $_POST['first-name'] ) );
    if ( !empty( $_POST['last-name'] ) )
        update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'last_name', esc_attr( $_POST['last-name'] ) );
    if ( !empty( $_POST['description'] ) )
        update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'description', esc_attr( $_POST['description'] ) );

    /* Redirect so the page will show updated info.*/
  /*I am not Author of this Code- i dont know why but it worked for me after changing below line to if ( count($error) == 0 ){ */
    if ( count($error) == 0 ) {
        //action hook for plugins and extra fields saving
        do_action('edit_user_profile_update', $current_user->ID);
        wp_redirect( get_permalink() );
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

then replace the loop of that page with this one:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <div class="entry-content entry">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <?php if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
                    <p class="warning">
                        <?php _e('You must be logged in to edit your profile.', 'profile'); ?>
                    </p><!-- .warning -->
            <?php else : ?>
                <?php if ( count($error) > 0 ) echo '<p class="error">' . implode("<br />", $error) . '</p>'; ?>
                <form method="post" id="adduser" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <p class="form-username">
                        <label for="first-name"><?php _e('First Name', 'profile'); ?></label>
                        <input class="text-input" name="first-name" type="text" id="first-name" value="<?php the_author_meta( 'first_name', $current_user->ID ); ?>" />
                    </p><!-- .form-username -->
                    <p class="form-username">
                        <label for="last-name"><?php _e('Last Name', 'profile'); ?></label>
                        <input class="text-input" name="last-name" type="text" id="last-name" value="<?php the_author_meta( 'last_name', $current_user->ID ); ?>" />
                    </p><!-- .form-username -->
                    <p class="form-email">
                        <label for="email"><?php _e('E-mail *', 'profile'); ?></label>
                        <input class="text-input" name="email" type="text" id="email" value="<?php the_author_meta( 'user_email', $current_user->ID ); ?>" />
                    </p><!-- .form-email -->
                    <p class="form-url">
                        <label for="url"><?php _e('Website', 'profile'); ?></label>
                        <input class="text-input" name="url" type="text" id="url" value="<?php the_author_meta( 'user_url', $current_user->ID ); ?>" />
                    </p><!-- .form-url -->
                    <p class="form-password">
                        <label for="pass1"><?php _e('Password *', 'profile'); ?> </label>
                        <input class="text-input" name="pass1" type="password" id="pass1" />
                    </p><!-- .form-password -->
                    <p class="form-password">
                        <label for="pass2"><?php _e('Repeat Password *', 'profile'); ?></label>
                        <input class="text-input" name="pass2" type="password" id="pass2" />
                    </p><!-- .form-password -->
                    <p class="form-textarea">
                        <label for="description"><?php _e('Biographical Information', 'profile') ?></label>
                        <textarea name="description" id="description" rows="3" cols="50"><?php the_author_meta( 'description', $current_user->ID ); ?></textarea>
                    </p><!-- .form-textarea -->

                    <?php 
                        //action hook for plugin and extra fields
                        do_action('edit_user_profile',$current_user); 
                    ?>
                    <p class="form-submit">
                        <?php echo $referer; ?>
                        <input name="updateuser" type="submit" id="updateuser" class="submit button" value="<?php _e('Update', 'profile'); ?>" />
                        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'update-user' ) ?>
                        <input name="action" type="hidden" id="action" value="update-user" />
                    </p><!-- .form-submit -->
                </form><!-- #adduser -->
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    </div><!-- .hentry .post -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <p class="no-data">
        <?php _e('Sorry, no page matched your criteria.', 'profile'); ?>
    </p><!-- .no-data -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

and all that is left for you to do is create a new page and select the "user profile" as the page template.

now if all of this is too much you can use some plugins that do the hard work for you like:

- [Frontend Edit Profile](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/frontend-edit-profile/)
- [WP User Frontend](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-user-frontend/)
- [Theme My Login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/)

Comment: when copying and pasting, insert the source link instead.

Comment: We've used ProfilePress in past projects to build front-end facing edit profile forms and we couldn't be more happy. see https://profilepress.net/features/wordpress-front-end-edit-profile-form/